# JQuery and MySQL data realtime graph

Tags: jquery, mysql, graph

How can i plot realtime data with jquery.
the data will be extracted from mysql, and i want to show these values on a page, where the plot graph should be realtime..

please help

Answer (score 2):

Here are some good `jquery graph plugins` check them out:
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/